# Proof or disproof that $f(x,y) = 2^x (2y + 1) - 1$ , where $f : N \times N \rightarrow N $ is a bijection.

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics

I need to poof or disproof that $f(x,y) = 2^x (2y + 1) - 1$ , where $f : \mathbb N \times \mathbb N \rightarrow \mathbb N $ is a bijection.

So think it's true. But I am having difficulties showing it.

Injection: Let $\langle a,b\rangle $ and $\langle c,d\rangle$ be a different pair of naturals $a \neq c \lor b \neq d$.
Then how can I show that $2^a (2b + 1) - 1 \neq 2^c (2d + 1) - 1 $?

Surjection: Let $n \in \mathbb N$. How can I show that there exist an pair that can be mapped in this $n$.

I am really stuck here.

Any help ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's assume that we have $a, b, c, d$ such that $$2^a(2b+1)-1=2^c(2d+1)-1$$
Then $$2^{a+1}b+2^a=2^{c+1}d+2^c$$
If $a=c$ then subtract $2^a$ and then divide by $2^{a+1}$ both sides, to get $b=d$. For the other cases, without loss of generality, assume $a<c$. Then divide the equation by $2^a$. You get
$$2b+1=2^{c-a+1}d+2^{c-a}$$
The left hand side is an odd number, the right hand side is even. So there is no such solution. So $f(a,b)=f(c,d)$ implies $a=c$ and $b=d$.

For surjection, you need to check for $n$ odd or even. If even, then $2^x=1$ or $x=0$. Can you take it from here?

Comment: What about tin surjection the odd case ? It's not as simple as the even case I think.

Comment: If $n=2k-1$ then $2^{x-1}(2y+1)=k$. Any number $k$ can be written as such. Keep dividing by $2$ until the remainder is $1$. The number of divisions is $x-1$. The quotient in the last division in an odd number, equal to $2y+1$

Answer (score 1):

For injectivity, the contrapositive is simpler: suppose that $2^a(2b+1)-1 = 2^c(2d+1)-1$. Adding $1$ to both sides we get $2^a(2b+1)=2^c(2d+1)$. By the Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic (unique factorization into primes) we conclude that $a=c$, and then cancelling that $b=d$.

For surjectivity, factor $n+1$ into a power of $2$ times an odd number.